# Можно ли отлавливать события мыши и клавиатуры?

Tags: c++, linux, callback

Хотелось бы знать, можно ли отловить нажатие мыши/клавиатуры на низком уровне. Для клавиатуры можно пробовать `scanf()` и считывать символ - но это не выход.

На простом примере: хочу создать консольное приложение, которое отловит разные события `move/click/motion` для мыши, и будет их, к примеру, выводить (`mouse click  btn_id=1 x=300 y=300`).

Есть ли хороший способ? (гугл пока не помог)

Comment: [curses?][1]

[1]: http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curses

Comment: не совсем то...но спасибо. Это либа я и сейчас с помощью другой либы могу создать окно и отлавливать на нём события. Но мне хотелось бы на системном уровне С++ отлавливать такого рода события.

Comment: @maxmail, напишите драйвер ядра.

Comment: если хочется очень низкий уровень - можно читать прямо с устройства "мышка". Вот готовая команда "на посмотреть"

    sudo cat /dev/input/mice | od -t x1 -w3

конечно, никто не мешает открыть файл `/dev/input/mice` и читать с него по три байта.

Comment: Для ввода с клавиатуры смотрите

man 2 read

и

man 2 ioctl

file descriptor = 0 (stdin)

Comment: KoVadim, я пробовал достучатся до файла /dev/input/mice с помощью которого можно считывать действия мыши, на сколько я понял, но при компиляции пишет ошибку при попытке открыть файл ("нет доступа" что-то подобное)...
Как можно выйти из ситуации?  Заранее спасибо

Comment: Видели в строке слово "sudo"?  это говорит, что нужно запускать от имени рута. Либо поиграть с правами.

Comment: причем тут "sudo"? я gcc файл в котором программно вызываю open(и указываю путь к /dev/input/mice)

Comment: потому что 

    ls /dev/input/mice -al
    crw-rw---- 1 root root 13, 63 May 19 09:51 /dev/input/mice

Answer (score 1):

ответ из комментариев:

если хочется очень низкий уровень - можно читать прямо с устройства "мышка". Вот готовая команда "на посмотреть":

```
$ sudo cat /dev/input/mice | od -t x1 -w3
```

конечно, никто не мешает открыть файл `/dev/input/mice` и читать с него по три байта.

---

Для ввода с клавиатуры смотрите `man 2 read` и `man 2 ioctl`

```
file descriptor = 0 (stdin)
```